# status: 400 title: "One or more validation errors occurred."

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angular, typescript

I am currently getting the 400 error code and I don't quite understand what is wrong. I have tried to search for answers online but none of the results are doing much help. Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

The JSON value could not be converted to TheMoonshineCafe.Models.Event. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.

It seems maybe the payload is not being converted into the Event type properly?

Edit event function from my data service:

```
  editEvent(id: Number, event: EventWithID[]){
    var callResult : any;
    console.log(id);
    console.log(event);
    this.http.put(this.baseUrl + 'api/Events/' + id, event).subscribe(result => {
      callResult = result;
      console.log(result);
    })
  }
```

Put Event from my API:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Event>> PutEvent(int id, Event @event)
        {
            if (id != @event.id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(@event).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!EventExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }
```

payload:

```
export class EventWithID {
    id: number;
    eventStart: Date;
    eventEnd: Date;
    refundCutOffDate: Date;
    bandName: String;
    bandImagePath: String;
    bandLink: String;
    maxNumberOfSeats: number;
    currentNumberOfSeats: number;
    ticketPrice: number;
    description: String;
  }
```

Models.Event:

```
public class Event
    {
        public int id {get; set; }
        public DateTime eventStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime eventEnd { get; set; }
        public DateTime refundCutOffDate { get; set; }
        public string bandName { get; set; }
        public string bandImagePath { get; set; }
        public string bandLink { get; set; }
        public int maxNumberOfSeats { get; set; }
        public int currentNumberOfSeats { get; set; }
        public double ticketPrice { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you stringify’ing your payload? Also, you don’t need that content-type header..

Comment: When I remove them, I get a status 400 error. I had seen some other people stringifying the payload and using the content-type header so I was wondering if I need to include something like that. I am a little confused as Create, Read and Delete all work so Put should work also.

Comment: With the correct setup you shouldn’t need either..

Comment: Alright well I guess I have to figure out this 400 error then, Thank you. Just very confusing that everything else works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix the  action

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<Event>> PutEvent(Event model)
   {
if(model.Id==0) return BadRequest("Wrong Id");
var existedEvent= await _context.Set<Event>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(i=> i.Id==model.Id);

            if (existedEvent==null ) return BadRequest("Record not found");

            _context.Entry(existedEvent).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);

          try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            ......
```

and javascript

```
  this.http.put(this.baseUrl + 'api/Events', event).subscribe(result => {
 ....
```

and instead  of put I highly recommend to use post.

Comment: I have tried to fix the action and the data service (typescript) however I now get an error:
error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Threading.CancellationToken'

Comment: @DerekS Did you check in debugger that model is not null?

Comment: @DerekS Sorry , I found a typo in my code, pls check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved things for us.